# Quiz in xml or database for Android

Tags: android

I have a question about making a quiz app.

Is it ok to have the questions in an xml file and load that. we are talking about alot of questions. Maybe 300 or so. Or should this be stored in somekind of a database instead?

Also if you have any links for this that would be good.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using a db is that you can categorize the questions and use db functions such as selecting a random row, or a specific question category.

You could also just use the assets folder and store text (or xml) files there. This is probably simplier but less flexible.

Answer (score 0):

store your questions in database, then only you can access that questions easily by question id.